# FlowRouter auto-redirect on login page

Tags: javascript, session, url-routing, meteor

The site should be accessible only to signed-in users. I'm making sure I publish and enable data manipulation to only those, but I wanna make sure even the app structure won't be visible.

What I did was creating an autorun that checks for changes in signed-in user and reloads the router. The router takes care of redirecting if needed.

```
let first_time = false;
Tracker.autorun(() => {
    Meteor.userId();
    if(first_time)
        FlowRouter.reload();
    else
        first_time = true;
});

FlowRouter.route(States.home,{
    triggersEnter: [(context, redirect) => {
        if(!Meteor.userId())
            redirect(States.login);
    }],
    action(params,queryParams){
        BlazeLayout.render('SimpleLayout', { content: "App"});
    }
});

FlowRouter.route(States.login,{
    action(params,queryParams){
        BlazeLayout.render('SimpleLayout', { content: "Login"});
    }
});
```

Are there any flaws?